# Marshall By Reference Inherit from class

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, marshalling

I've got a problem with multiple inheritance and MarshallByRefObj

The problem i have is that I need to inherit from an abstract class AND MarshallByRefObj

The abstract class (stripped down) :

```cs
public abstract class Drawable : IDrawable
{
    //... Several unimportant methods...
    public IEnumerable<ICard> Shuffle (IEnumerable<ICard>)
    {
        //...shuffle the cards here...
    }
}
```

The class I'm trying to make, which needs to be accessed by reference through wcf
Stripped down, obviously...:

```
public class Deck : Drawable, MarshallByRefObject
{
    //... public stuff that implements a deck to include 
    // search/draw/discard functions...
}
```

Comment: Why not make Drawable inherit from MBRO?

Comment: C# does not support mutiple inheritance for classes. You can, however, inherit multiple interfaces. If your abstract class provides implentation, then you will need to follow Kirk Woll's advice, I think.

Comment: I can't make Drawable inherit from MBRO in this case as i don't have access to it.

Comment: Your requirement is to inherit from two class types, neither of which you control. Your requirement cannot be met in a single-inheritance language. Abandon your requirement and replace it with one that can be met.

Comment: I think his requirement did change, and the change is that what is really wanted is a MBRO that implements IDrawable, not a hybrid MBRO/Drawable object. Still, it seems to me that proxying an interface to an internal member that implements it is kind of a pattern. I've certainly done it a fair number of times. Do you see this as being enough of a pattern to ponder a language extension to do that automatically and concisely?

Comment: To be more specific as to the changes, I had to refactor some code that used Drawable to use IDrawable instead, and then used a private Drawable implementation inside a wrapper class with the signature:

`public class Deck : IDrawable, MarshalByRefObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deriving from MarshalByRefObject, and implementing the interface of the other class. Then, define a member of that class' type and make your interface just proxy calls to it. It's a pain, but it's straightforward.

```
public class Deck : MarshalByRefObject, IDrawable
{
    Drawable _drawable = new Drawable(...);

    // Implement IDrawable
    void IDrawable.Foo() { _drawable.Foo(); }
    void IDrawable.Bar() { _drawable.Bar(); }
}
```

Comment: That's good, but what do I do if Drawable implements methods not in the interface (as is the case here it turns out)?  If it were entirely up to me, I'd refactor it into a true interface/abstract set and use this solution, but it's not up to me, so what's next?  More specifically, what do I do when a consumer wants Drawable, and all I have to offer is IDrawable?

Comment: Second look, All contents of Drawable are in IDrawable, so this method will work, thanks!